# AlertView triggering keyboard after dismissal

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

So this is happening.

I have one view controller and it handles all of the alert views in my app. I have another view controller that has a UITextView that the user can edit, and a save button.

When they hit the save button, if the text is already saved, it triggers an alert that asks them if they're sure they want to update, and if they confirm, it updates the file and gives them a second alert that says it was a success.

What's happening is that the keyboard keeps popping up when the second alert appears. I've tried resigning the keyboard and turning off the user interaction enabled flag on the text field as soon as the save button is hit.

```
self.storyEditorTextView.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
[self.storyEditorTextView resignFirstResponder];
```

I've also tried to turn it off when the alert is responded to (since some alerts can have a textfield).

To make matters worse, when I comment out the resign and userInteractionsEnabled lines, including the one in the alert, the keyboard still appears after the first alert is dismissed, disappears when the second alert is dismissed (if you can tap it because the keyboard covers it), and you can't tap into the UITextView and bring up the keyboard without going back to the parent view.

Here's the alert code.

```
- (void)addPromptToFavorites
{
// throw up an alert to confirm and get a name
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Name Your Favorite!" 
                                                        message:@"Would you like to add a name to your prompt?"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];
        // add a text field
        alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
        UITextField *textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
        textField.text = @"My Great Prompt";

        // set the tag
        [alert setTag:SAVE_FAVE];

        // Display the alert to the user
        [alert show];
}


- (void)updateFave: (NSNumber *) theFaveId
{
    NSLog(@"UPDATE FAVE\n\nself.sharedFaveMan.tempFave %@",self.sharedFaveMan.tempFave);
   // NSMutableDictionary *faveDict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // loop through the favoritePrompts array until you find a match to the faveID
    for (id element in self.sharedFaveMan.favoritePrompts) {
        NSNumber *valueForID = [element valueForKey:@"id"];

        if([valueForID isEqualToNumber:theFaveId])
        {
            self.sharedFaveMan.tempFave=element;
        }
    }

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Update Your Favorite!"
                                                    message:@"The story will be saved with the currently selected Favorite."
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];

    //set the tag
    [alert setTag:UPDATE_FAVE];

    // Display the alert to the user
    [alert show];

}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    if (buttonIndex !=0)
    {
      if(alertView.tag==UPDATE_FAVE)
        {
            NSLog(@"Updating Fave");
            // loop through the favoritePrompts array until you find a match to the faveID
            int counter=0;
            for (id element in self.sharedFaveMan.favoritePrompts) {
                NSNumber *valueForID = [element valueForKey:@"id"];

                if([valueForID isEqualToNumber:self.sharedFaveMan.theFaveID]){
                    break;
                }
                counter ++;
            }


            // update the pieces of the prompt
            [[self.sharedFaveMan.favoritePrompts objectAtIndex:counter] setObject:self.sharedFaveMan.faveStoryText forKey:@"storyText"];

            // save it
            [self saveFavorites];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
             postNotificationName:@"updateTheTable"
             object:self];

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!"
                                                            message:@"Favorite Updated!"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];

            //play a sound
            [self createSoundID: @"ticktock.aiff"];

            //set the tag
            [alert setTag:UPDATE_COMPLETE];

            // Display the alert to the user
            [alert show];

        }
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)alertView.tag);

        if(alertView.tag==SAVE_FAVE)
        {
            // they canceled the save

        }
        else if (alertView.tag==UPDATE_COMPLETE)
        {
            NSLog(@"Hit that");
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
             postNotificationName:@"dismissedDialogNotification"
             object:self];
        }
    }

}

-(BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    if (textField && [textField.text length] == 0)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Honestly, when it comes to alerts, less is more. I would abandon the saved success alert and only show a failure alert - and only if the user can do something about it, such as connect to the Internet. - because they are bothersome and a pain. Apple also advises against showing success as an alert. If you really want to show success, flash a color over the background or something quick and unobtrusive that doesn't require interaction. As the keyboard only comes up for the second one this should also fix your problem.

Comment: Well, I have to say that was a surprising suggestion. It's the easiest to do programming-wise, and it's nice for the UI too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {    
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        // Return FALSE so that the final '\n' character doesn't get added
        return NO;
    }
    // For any other character return TRUE so that the text gets added to the view
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
     [textView resignFirstResponder];
     return true;
}
```

and in alert method at the begining add this line of code

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```